# Unable to export the build pipeline which is created by YAML on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline

I created a build pipeline on Azure DevOps by using YAML syntax. Now, I would like to export that build pipeline, but the button "Export" the build is unable to click. Does the build pipeline is create by YAML can export to JSON?

Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes no sense really. you have a yaml file, why do you need to export it again? just copy it.